# mysql change all values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to change all values in the tablecolumn "Quellendatum".

When the row-value is 2005-06-20 then it should be replaced with 2012-06-20.
When the row-value is NULL or empty, then it should be untouched.

Currently i modify this manually by selecting the row:

```
UPDATE  `outgoing2`.`tbl_hochschule` 
SET  `Quellendatum` =  '2012-06-20' 
WHERE  `tbl_hochschule`.`id` =1;
```

Is there a way to automate this task?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

How about:

```
UPDATE outgoing2.tbl_hochschule 
SET Quellendatum = '2012-06-20' 
WHERE Quellendatum = '2005-06-20' 
AND !isnull( Quellendatum );
```

Answer (score 12):

In MySql you can do:

```
UPDATE TABLENAME    
SET IDCOLUMN=VALUE    
WHERE IDCOLUMN=VALUE    
AND !isnull (IDCOLUMN)
```

Answer (score 6):

it should be :

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET Quellendatum = '2012-06-20' 
WHERE Quellendatum = '2005-06-20'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE outgoing2.tbl_hochschule 
SET Quellendatum = '2012-06-20' 
WHERE Quellendatum <> '' AND Quellendatum <> NULL;
```

Comment: expression `Quellendatum <> NULL` is illegal. You should use `Quellendatum is not NULL` instead

Answer (score 0):

If **Quellendatum = "2005-06-20"** then it can't be NULL. So I don't see the use of ' `AND !isnull (Quellendatum)`

Comment: Is this question or answer ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30012406)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SET COLUMN_NAME = " "
```

This will update all the values in a column