# How to convert 50000 to .5 lakhs in postgres query

Tags: postgresql

```
Select * from employee;

ID  name       salary
1   karthi      30000
2   Thushara    70000
3   Divya       150000
```

How do I convert to this?

```
ID  name       salary
1   karthi      0.3 lakhs
2   Thushara    0.7 lakhs
3   Divya       1.5 lakhs
```

See [Indian Numbering System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)

Comment: Please read [ask]. Also read & act on [mcve] and hits from googling 'stackexchange homework'. Read the downvote arrow mouseover text. Show what you have googled--*many* different phrasings of your problem/question/desiderata. This is a faq. Also what you have tried. Use *one* SQL tag for the SQL you are *using*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql change all values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430009/mysql-change-all-values-in-a-column)

Comment: `salary / 100000`?

Comment: This should really be done in the UI, not in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   id,
   name,
   CONCAT(salary/100000,' lakhs') as salary
FROM
   employee;
```

Comment: You should add details/explanation for answer.