# PSQL convert/hash all values in a column

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, psql

A database for a PHP web server is initialized as follows:
[image]
I would like to encrypt all the passwords in the account table using PostgresSQL's crypt() function from the pgcrypto module. Essentially, if this was a regular programming language, this code:

```
for password in passwd:
    set password = crypt(password, my encryption method)
```

How would I accomplish this on SQL? Is there a way? I am open to a PHP solution as well if necessary.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507477/postgresql-update-inside-for-loop) doesn't seem to have a way to reference the variable in passwords for further use; not to mention it is dependent on different columns. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430009/mysql-change-all-values-in-a-column) requires you to know the value of each password, and in effect do it manually.

Comment: If you are going to use the password in a PHP application, I would recommend looking into using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: crypting inside the query is all well and fine but then you must use SSL for the connection else mitm can just read plaintext.. which adds a layer of setup and maintenance complexity https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ssl-tcp.html is much easier to do in code and send the hash over the wire instead

Comment: Yeah I'll do an SSL, and password_hash() etc. looks useful as well, thanks. My original question about converting the for loop I showed above into SQL code still stands... or perhaps I would have to do it in PHP

Comment: just use an `UPDATE account SET passwd = crypt(passwd, my encryption method)`, you dont need any sort of loop.. rtm: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-update.html

Comment: note the varchar(50) before doing, you wouldn't want the values truncated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of this pseudo-code:

```
for password in passwd:
    set password = crypt(password, my encryption method)
```

Is an `update` statement:

```
update t
    set password = crypt(password, . . .);
```

SQL is a set-based language.  SQL queries do not have a looping mechanism because the language is operating on entire tables (or filtered subsets thereof).

You can add a `where` clause if you want to filter the rows so not all are updated.